# How to store persitent JSON data in HTML5 mobilie app

Tags: javascript, android, json, html, cordova

I am using PhoneGap to develop a HTML based mobile app.

On Loading the app for the first time, I want the app to download a zip file containing a JSON file, and media files (like image or audio).

Once, this zip is downloaded, I will extract the contents and get the JSON file and load the data into the app. 
But I want to store this JSON data in a persistent way, so that even if the phone is switched off the data is available to the app.

Once an update of the file is available (this update will only be partial update which will not contain all the same data again but will contain updates to only  certain data from the original JSON file).

I dont know how to do this. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: you can use sqlite or indexedDB or if you only have a bit, localStorage. localStorage is the simplest, it's just an object that only stores strings and doesn't get reset upon reload.

Comment: Once you download it first time store it in localstorage with a version number so you can check on app start up for updates.

Comment: you can also use HTML manifests to make certain URLs work offline for the app, and it gives you a common way of pushing updates, and works out of cordova.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will choose IndexedDB. But is IndexedDB compatible with Android, iOS, and Windows phones, if I use it in HTML5 and PhoneGap based mobile application?

Comment: Also, Is there a javascript plugin that handles this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Application Cache interface to persist your data as explained here:

[A Beginner's Guide to Using the Application Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

You need to create an appcache manifest file and reference it like so:

```
 <html manifest="example.appcache">
  ...
 </html>
```

A great tool I use to populate the appcache file is called [ManifestR](http://westciv.com/tools/manifestR/).

Comment: Thanks, I am not looking for Manifest or application cache. I am looking at persisting data locally in mobile phones.